# Reg Query in script not working when executed remotely with psexec

Tags: batch-file

I have recently gotten a script together for querying the reg for a temp folder path and cleaning the folder and it works great(Thanks Compo) but when used remotely with psexec it says, "The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value."  Before I use PSEXEC to execute the batch I first have it copied to the C:\ and I use this to do that.

```
set /p cpu=

robocopy "\\nmcfs01\software\scripts\Jacob's Awesome Outlook Scripts" \\%cpu%\c$\Jacob'sTemp
```

That part goes well then I execute it with psexec with

```
psexec \\%cpu% -u administrator -i -d "C:\Jacob'sTemp\compo.bat"
```

That connects but when it executes the batch file it does not find the reg key.  HOWEVER, if I go to the C:\Jacob'sTemp and double click on the compo.bat file it works fine and deletes out the files.  Also, if I just use PSEXEC to execute it again outside of this script just separately after it is copied over it still does not work.  Here is the script I am using for cleaning it up.

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

(Set OV=14.0)

Choice /C YN /M "Delete Outlook Temp Files?"
If ErrorLevel 2 Exit/B
Set "BK=HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\"
Set "EK=\Outlook\Security"
Set "VN=OutlookSecureTempFolder"
For /F "Tokens=2*" %%I In ('Reg Query "%BK%%OV%%EK%" /V %VN%') Do Set "VD=%%J"
PushD "%VD%" && (RD/S/Q "%VD%" 2>Nul) && PopD
pause
REM The below commands will empty Jacob'sTemp:
If Exist "%SystemDrive%\Jacob'sTemp" (PushD "%SystemDrive%\Jacob'sTemp" && (
    (RD/S/Q "%SystemDrive%\Jacob'sTemp" 2>Nul) && PopD
pause
REM The below commands without the first two characters will remove Jacob'sTemp
If Exist "%SystemDrive%\Jacob'sTemp" (RD/S/Q "%SystemDrive%\Jacob'sTemp"
Pause
Echo(------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Echo( Complete!  Goodbye!
Echo(------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Timeout 5 >Nul
```

It would be a huge help to have this work as intended where we can just type the computer name in and done but I do not know why it does not work when executed remotely and it is copied to the computer.  Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: If you find no other solutions, you could use the [StdRegProv class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35301457/1683264) as an alternative to `reg.exe`.

Comment: I wasn't sure of your requirements for the Jacob'sTemp directory hence the included **REM**arks and **::** commented line. If as it appears from your edit you do not require the Jacob'sTemp directory to remain on the remote PC then you can remove lines: 13, 14, 15, 16 and 18 of your script. If you do wish Jacob'sTemp to remain, but just empty it then remove lines: 14, 18, 19 and 20 of the script.

Comment: That was for when I copied them with robo copy before this script is executed.  So the file itself is deleted is all but it doesn't work when I execute it with psexec.

Answer (score 1):

HKCU, the target of your reg query, is a per user registry hive. psexec's remote service runs in SYSTEM account and when it issues reg query that wont be directed to the remote machine's currently logged-in user's HKCU. It would be directed to the SYSTEM account's HKCU which maps under HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software.... Hence the error "The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value."